# How do I share my internet connection for a VPN when I get it from a router?

Tags: windows, networking, router, vpn, openvpn

Alright, I have this setup:

- A common router with outgoing PPPoE connection to my ISP which provides me internet.
- A computer connected through the LAN to the router, default settings including DHCP, internet successefully available on the computer.
- A friend of mine (with his own internet) **is in deep need of MY internet**, so is means that
- That person above needs to access my internet from my router somehow.
- I have created a VPN incoming connection (Windows 8.1) and specified a user with a password.
- I have created a port forwarding (from 1 to 35k) on the router to my computer.
- The friend of mine successefully connects (through the internet) to my "Incoming Connections" thing and I see him as a user which have logged in.
- **Issue:** he loses his internet at all when he is at me.

Solution required: some setup with my router or (preferred) my windows network options so he could have my internet.

Something we have tried:

- Create bridge connection with my LAN and "Incoming Connecitons". No result, no such option in the context menu when I select both of them.
- Install OpenVPN and try there. No success (same issue) there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The thing is to create an appropriate pool of IP addresses on the Incoming Connections thing. It must be the same subnet as router's, like **192.168.XX.XX**.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that your friend wants simultaneous access through two ISPs? His ISP and your ISP through the VPN?

I think the issue would be that his PC can only call one Gateway at a time.

VPN off > requests for stuff on non-local IPs go to his modem.
VPN on >  requests for stuff on non-local IPs go though the VPN to your modem.